# Unable to free space in /boot

Tags: server, boot, apt, dpkg

Running:
Linux ips-svf-1 3.0.0-22-server #36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 12 17:56:20 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I'm trying to free space in /boot with apt-get -y purge, but every time I run the command I get an error about unmet dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get -y purge linux-headers-3.0.0-12
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-headers-3.0.0-12-server : Depends: linux-headers-3.0.0-12 but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-server : Depends: linux-image-3.0.0-26-server but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

However, I can't run `apt-get -f install` since /boot is full.

I also tried running `dpkg --purge` and dpkg `--remove` manually, but both give the same unmet dependency error.

Any suggestions on how I can successfully free space in /boot?  Is there anything I can safely delete with rm?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies) or (more likely) [**How do I free up more space in /boot?**](http://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**use with caution**

```
dpkg --force-depends ....
```

or ***use with caution***

```
dpkg --force-all ....
```

For more information invoke:

```
dpkg --force-help
```

Comment: That's working to allow dpkg to proceed, but strangely, df is showing no change in blocks used in /boot.  Boot is still 100% full  Any idea why?

Comment: 1. Check if some slack like core files are below /boot

Comment: 2. Purge some unused kernels (check before with uname -a which kernel is running)

Comment: (Most likely 3.0.0-12 and 3.0.0-26 are not properly installed.)

Comment: Ah, got it now - I was purging headers (which were at the top of the list) and not seeing space freed because they were so small.  Once I purged an actual kernel, enough space was freed so I could run `apt-get -f install` and then could purge the remaining kernels with plain old `apt-get purge -y <kernel>`